# Why does no sound play with Realtek ALC260 driver in Debian?

Tags: debian, audio

I recently installed Debian 8 on a GoBook XR-1 laptop. Debian detects it as having a Realtek ALC260 sound card.

- The sound card worked fine when Windows was installed.
- I previously had an identical model of laptop running Debian 7 and sound worked after following the steps found at [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313952/sound-not-working) . These steps failed in Debian 8, causing Debian 8 to not boot up until I deleted the files in recovery mode.
- I unmuted sound using `alsamixer`.

  ```
  ┌──────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.0.28 ────────────────────────┐
  │ Card: HDA Intel                           F1:  Help               │
  │ Chip: Realtek ALC260                      F2:  System information │
  │ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All  F6:  Select sound card  │
  │ Item: Master [dB gain: -20.00]            Esc: Exit               │
  │    ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     │
  │    │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     │
  │    │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │▒▒│     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │▒▒│     │  │     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     →
  │    │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │  │     │  │     │
  │    ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     │
  │    │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │MM│     │MM│     │MM│     │MM│     │
  │    └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     │
  │     41       25    100<>100   1<>1     0<>0     0<>0     0<>0     │
  │ < Master >Speaker    PCM      Line      CD      Mic      Beep     │
  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
  ```
- I also tried changing from the HDA Intel/Realtek ALC260 to PulseAudio in `alsamixer`.

  ```
  ┌──────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.0.28 ────────────────────────┐
  │ Card: PulseAudio                          F1:  Help               │
  │ Chip: PulseAudio                          F2:  System information │
  │ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All  F6:  Select sound card  │
  │ Item: Master                              Esc: Exit               │
  │                               ┌──┐                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               │▒▒│                                │
  │                               ├──┤                                │
  │                               │OO│                                │
  │                               └──┘                                │
  │                              97<>97                               │
  │                            < Master >                             │
  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
  ```
- I tried unmuting sound from the FN keys.
- I tried using an external speaker, and using it without.
- When I play an MP3 with `mplayer`, then run `pavucontrol`, the bar `pavucontrol` indicates that sound is playing. When I mute the sound in `alsamixer`, this bar stops moving.

Output of `dmesg | grep snd`:

```
[    9.499756] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
```

Output of `dmesg | grep sound`:

```
[   10.029252] sound hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0xf/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   10.029258] sound hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x11/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   10.029262] sound hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   10.029265] sound hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   10.029268] sound hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   10.029271] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
[   10.029274] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x14
[   10.029277] sound hdaudioC0D0:      CD=0x16
[   10.094057] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/hdaudioC0D0/input15
```

Output of `sudo alsactl init`:

```
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC260" "HDA:10ec0260,02601635,00100400 HDA:10573055,10573055,00100700" "0x14ff" "0xa001"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

Output of `lspci -nn | grep Audio`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
```

**Update**

- Turning off PulseAudio with `pulseaudio --kill`, then switching `alsamixer` to the audio card does not work, even when testing `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`.

Output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC260
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0260
Subsystem Id: 0x02601635
Revision Id: 0x100400
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=4, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[3]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x11: Stereo
  Device: name="ALC260 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x211: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x04 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10011b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC260 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x23, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x0c 0x0c]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Connection: 7
     0x12* 0x13 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x0f 0x10
Node 0x05 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10011b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC260 Alt Analog", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x23, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Connection: 8
     0x12* 0x13 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x07 0x0f 0x10
Node 0x06 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100391: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x19
Node 0x07 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="CD Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="CD Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=5, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=5, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x23, nsteps=0x41, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x33 0x33] [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00] [0x2d 0x2d] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 8
     0x12 0x13 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x0f 0x10
Node 0x08 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="PCM Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2f 0x2f]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x07
Node 0x09 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x07
Node 0x0a [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010e: Mono Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00] [0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x23, nsteps=0x41, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x2d]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x07
Node 0x0b [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 2
     0x08* 0x09
Node 0x0c [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 2
     0x08* 0x09
Node 0x0d [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 2
     0x08* 0x09
Node 0x0e [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 2
     0x08* 0x09
Node 0x0f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="PCM Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Out Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001003f: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect Trigger ImpSense
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x01014110: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x08
Node 0x10 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0001003f: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect Trigger ImpSense
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x09
Node 0x11 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40010c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Speaker Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x99030120: [Fixed] Line Out at Int ATAPI
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Connection: 1
     0x0a
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x01a1993e: [Jack] Mic at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0xe
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x21: IN VREF_50
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0b
Node 0x13 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Line Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x01813130: [Jack] Line In at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Blue
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0e
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400001: Stereo
  Control: name="CD Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x99330131: [Fixed] CD at Int ATAPI
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x1
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400000: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x99830132: [Fixed] Line In at Int ATAPI
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x2
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400380: Mono Digital
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400280: Mono Digital
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x1a [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=13
Node 0x1b [Volume Knob Widget] wcaps 0x600080: Mono
  Volume-Knob: delta=0, steps=64, direct=0, val=61
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 0
Codec: Motorola Si3054
Address: 1
MFG Function Id: 0x2 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10573055
Subsystem Id: 0x10573055
Revision Id: 0x100700
Modem Function Group: 0x1
```

Output of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub [8086:27a0] (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port [8086:27a1] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 [8086:27d2] (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 [8086:27d4] (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 [8086:27d6] (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801GR/GH/GHM (ICH7 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:27e0] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GHM (ICH7-M DH) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27bd] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:27c4] (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370/M22 [Mobility Radeon X300] [1002:5460]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: LSI Corporation ET-131x PCI-E Ethernet Controller [11c1:ed00] (rev 03)
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
0b:03.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ711MP1/MS1 MemoryCardBus Controller [1217:7134] (rev 21)
0b:03.1 CardBus bridge [0607]: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ711MP1/MS1 MemoryCardBus Controller [1217:7134] (rev 21)
0b:03.4 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) [1217:00f7] (rev 02)
```

What can I do to get sound working on my laptop?

Comment: The usual steps to debug audio: (1) Stop Pulseaudio, try to play a `wav` file with `aplay -D plughw:0 filename.wav`. If that works, (2) check in `pavucontrol` that applications take correct output, etc. If it doesn't work: (3) Put output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` and `lspci -nn` into a pastebin, edit question with link. Modern kernels *do* support ALC260, and there are quite a few quirks in the source to deal with various systems, maybe your laptop needs one of those.

Comment: @dirkt I have test `aplay` with PulseAudio off, but this did not work. I also updated my question to include the outputs from those two commands.

Answer (score 2):

Quick explanation of the codec dump from `/proc`: Intel HDA codecs are presented as a graph with nodes. `Connection` lists the are input into the current node. So for example, the audio output node `0x02` goes into mixer node `0x08`, which goes into the pin complex node `0x0f`, which should be connected to the `line out` jack at the rear side.

However, while the line out jack, the line in jack and the mic jack are hopefully correctly labelled, the "internal line out mono, ATAPI" at node `0x11` seems bogus: The product description of the GoBook XR-1 says there are two internal speakers, so I'd expect stereo, and also not "line out", but "speaker", and no "ATAPI". Nevertheless, this is the node which is designated as speaker - but it's probably the wrong node.

So you definitely need some sort of quirk fixup (there's quite a few quirks that assign the speaker/headphone to some node). File a bug with the ALSA developers, give them the codec info, and also subsystem vendor/id of the audio card (`lspci -s 00:1b.0 -v -nn`).

If you feel brave, you can play around with `hdajackretask` (Debian package `alsa-tools-gui`), and see if you can find the real speaker pin node. (I'm not sure if this will re-assign the correct controls, so always look at the codec after you changed the pins).

It's interesting that it worked with the `snd_hda_codec_realtek` drivers, though - maybe there's some other way to read the correct configuration.